# How to assign a name to a membership number vice versa?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts

I would like to learn what formula I can use to make my timesheet more efficient.

1. How to assign a membership number to a name vice versa? I need to add lesson hours to each membership daily and typing the membership numbers, and the same each time take a lot of time.

Is there a way where I can link the members' numbers and the members' names together?

[image]

2. How to assign a price to a text? I have different type of lessons, would like to be able to type in the type of lesson and the price can automaticly appear.
   P=$675 ; SP=$350
   [image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you describe is usually implemented by creating one or more *lookup tables* in a separate tab. You can then use `vlookup()` to find names by membership numbers, membership numbers by names, and prices by lesson types. See [VLOOKUP Function in Google Sheets](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/vlookup-function/).